# When To Use @SessionAttribute Over @ModelAttribute

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm having a hard time figuring out a specific time in which one would use `@SessionAttribute` over `@ModelAttribute`.

This question arose because after making a web application I realised that I have got a lot of methods that I passed in `Principal principal` to. In these methods, I use `principal.getName()` to get the username of the logged-in user and then retrieve the relevant data from the database using that username. In short, a lot of my methods needed access to the current user data and I resolved this in what I believe to be an inefficient manner.

To rectify this I was going to create a model attribute in a class annotated with `@ControllerAdvice`, in which I get the principal and get the user data from the database and add it to the model.

E.g `model.addAttribute("currentUser", currentUser);`

so that in the parameter list of these methods I can have `(@ModelAttribute("currentUser") UserAccount currentUser)`
saving unnecessary work by getting the principal and then proceeding to get the user from the database.

While I don't know a whole lot about `@SessionAttribute`, I feel like this sort of `data(UserAccount currentUser)` is more relevant to the session as opposed to the model. Am I Wrong?

I also heard that `@SessionAttribute` doesn't make its data available across multiple controllers which in this case I need. Hence why I'm using `@ControllerAdvice`.

My questions are as follows:

1. What is the best practice for implementing the above where I need to
   repeatedly access the current users data. Maybe I can further increase efficiency by adding a current user bean on login and then use `@Autowired` so that I wouldn't even need to have `currentUser` in the parameter list. But I don't know if that's even possible. Is it?
2. Is it true that the method annotated with `@ModelAttribute` is called
   prior to every `@RequestMapping`, `@GetMapping`, `@PostMapping` etc. call?
   and that an object specific to `@SessionAttribute` remains in the
   model for the duration of the session?
3. Also In what situation should I user `@SessionAttribute` over
   `@ModelAttribute`?

Answer (score 0):

The [`@SessionAttrributes`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/SessionAttributes.html) annotation is for the use-case where you need to have a model attribute that you need to access over multiple screens. Like doing a checkout for a shopping cart, you would store the `Order` in the session, screen 1, confirm, screen 2 payment details, screen 3, delivery details, screen 4 OK. After screen 4 you would then call [`SessionStatus.setComplete()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/support/SessionStatus.html) and it will clean that attribute.

That is the use case for `@SessionAttributes` and **should** be used in conjunction with `@ModelAttribute`. It is not intended to be used to store a, for instance, the user in the session for the duration of the `HttpSession`.

The [`@SessionAttribute`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/SessionAttribute.html) (a different annotation!) is to retrieve an attribute from the `HttpSession` that was placed there earlier. In your case after authentication, you would place the `User` in the `HttpSession` with `HttpSession.setAttribute("currentUser", user);`. In a controller method, you could use `@SessionAttribute("currentUser") User user` to retrieve and use it. No need for an `@ControllerAdvice` or model attribute anymore.

However I would strongly to ditch your custom security implementation and use something like [Spring Security](https://spring.io/projects/spring-security) instead. That way all that, and more, is already provided out of the box. In a controller method you can then use the `@AuthenticationPrincipal` annotation to retrieve the current user.